# disk information for KVM VPS

Tags: hard-drive, vps

Is there a way to determine if a local disk in a kvm vps is hosted on local storage  or a remote?
I need to find if the disk of my kvm vps on hosted on local's hypervisor's disk array or via a remote storage.

Comment: From within the VPS or from the hypervisor?

Comment: i have only access to the vps itself

Answer (score 5):

You cannot see from VM, where virtual disk is hosted. Ask your VPS provider.

Comment: Indeed. And the OP's real concern should not be what the actual back-end is but if the VPS delivers the agreed upon performance, reliability and disaster recovery (if any)